# Executing two commands into one command in R

Tags: r, list, file, command

I have 12 files in my directory folder, the type of the files is csv and SAS7dbat. I used this command to upload them:

```
fileList1 = list.files(path=".", pattern=".csv") 
fileList2 = list.files(path=".", pattern=".sas")
```

I tried to write this command, but it didn't go well:

```
fileList = list.files(path=".", pattern= c(".csv", ".sas")
```

In addition, I need two make them to one command:

```
  list2env(
lapply(setNames(fileList1, make.names(paste(2008:2016, "_kvish_1_10t",   sep= ""))), 
      read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)

list2env(
lapply(setNames(fileList2, make.names(paste0(2005:2007, "_kvish_1_10t", sep= ""))),
       haven::read_sas), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern only takes one argument.

If you want to find several elements, you should try with a regex :

```
fileList <- list.files(path=".", pattern= "\\.csv|\\.sas")
```

Best,

Colin

Comment: Or `list.files(path = "\\.(csv|sas)$")`, I guess.

Comment: Hey, can you please answer my second question that I added to the post. I tried in the same way you showed me